snap cursor to curve point in object mode
Is there a way to just drag the 3d Cursor to a curve point using a keyboard command/drag method? I tried to find a way but couldn't.
I have curve data at which I want to create primitives. Currently when I go Add > Mesh > Cube and the object is created at the 3d cursor.
I'd like the object to be created at the curve point so I go into edit mode and select the point then Shift S and select "move cursor to selection" then Add > Mesh > Cube. That's better but still a lot of steps.
Thank you.



In the snapping options popover, set the Snap Base to Center, and Snap Target to Vertex

Hold down ⇧ Shift RMB to move the cursor around
While moving the cursor, hold down ⎈ Ctrl to toggle snapping.



That works great, thank you!
